# Dragging item from UITableView and dropping in UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop in my app, with the user dragging an item from a table view and dropping it into a custom view.

My table view implements `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath)` from UITableViewDragDelegate and my custom view implements the necessary functions from UIDropInteractionDelegate. The table view's `dragInteractionEnabled` property is set to true, and its drag delegate is set to self.

Dragging from the table view works, but I can't drop those items into my custom view (none of the dropInteraction functions are called at all). However, dropping a random file (say, an image) into the custom view *does* work, and the dropInteraction functions are called. I'm not sure if it matters, but the table view is in a view controller that is a child of the view controller that controls the custom view.

Here's my itemsForBeginning table view function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
    dragItem.localObject = components[indexPath.item]
    return [dragItem]
}
```

Here is the code in my custom view for accepting the drop. This code is not complete, I'm just trying to get it to run.

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    for dragItem in session.items {
        print(dragItem.itemProvider)
    }
}
    
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}
     
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. This app runs on iOS 14, iPadOS 14 and MacCatalyst (currently testing on macOS 10.15.7, so macCatalyst 13). It works on iOS and iPadOS, but not on macOS, despite 10.15.7 supporting this feature.

Comment: Did you declare the types that your view should receive ?

Comment: I did not, I didn't see anything online about that. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Two thoughts. First, what *exactly* are you seeing? You've only posted code related to dragging and *not* dropping. (Also, are you using an iPhone? iOS 15? Or an iPad? Sorry for screaming this, but THIS MATTERS!) Next, what's exactly is your drop target? The only code you've posted is drag. For iOS (and iPadOS) a drag is one thing but a drop is another. What @koen is addressing is the drop - your view needs to tell the "drag" view what it can accept.

Comment: @dfd I've edited my post with more information and code. I probably should have given more context on the versions I'm using, as this issue seems to only affect macOS (Catalyst)